# I want to know source id of where contact has been created, means if any contact created on google then I want to know it's unique contact id

Tags: android, android-contacts, contacts, google-contacts-api

I have found RAW_CONTACT_ID & SOURCE_ID can be useful for this. But I am not able to find it programatically. Below is the code I am trying.

```
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, new String[]
    {ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID}, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                            new String[]{String.valueOf(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)))}, null);
    try {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            long rawContactId = c.getLong(0);
            LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod("==  rawContactId  ===", "" + rawContactId);
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();
    }
Log.e(TAG, "cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID)):  " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID)));
Log.e(TAG, "cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID):  " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
Log.e(TAG, "cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)):  " + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
```

I am getting error :

```
CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 38 columns.
```

System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Please let me know any error in my code.

updated Code : `Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID},
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                    null,
                    null);
            try {
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    long rawContactId = cur.getLong(0);
                    LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod("==  rawContactId  ===", "" + rawContactId);
                    LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod(TAG, "ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID:  "
                            + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID)));
                    LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod(TAG, "ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID:  "
                            + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
                    LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod(TAG, "ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID:  "
                            + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID)));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                cur.close();
            }`

Answer (score 0):

1. You're trying to read from a cursor after you've called `Cursor.close()` on it, which means it's now closed and cannot be accessed anymore.
   Move those 3 lines from the end into your try/finally clause.
2. You're trying to access field `RawContacts.SOURCE_ID` without specifying it in your projection - change your projection to `new String[]{ RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.SOURCE_ID }`
3. You're trying to access fields from `Data.XXX` by querying the `RawContacts.CONTENT_URI` table, this is not possible, you need to query the `Data.CONTENT_URI` table if you need fields from `Data`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please check my query it's not working, please correct me :  Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID},
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                    null,
                    null);

Comment: you should update your question instead of putting code in comments. anyway, if you're using `?` in the selection field, you have to put some value in the 4th field of the query - `selectionArgs`